# Permutating an array, and getting a certain amount of items from that array

Tags: javascript

SO far, I have this:

```js
function permutate(UwU){
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < UwU.length; i = i + 1) {
        let slice = permutate(UwU.slice(0, i).concat(UwU.slice(i + 1)));
    
        if(!slice.length) {
            array.push([UwU[i]])
        } else {
          for(let j = 0; j < slice.length; j = j + 1) {
            array.push([UwU[i]].concat(slice[j]))
          }
        }
      }
      return array;
    }
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "P", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

   const overload = permutate(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "P", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]).join("\n")
   console.log(overload)
```

Obviously there's way too many variations, so how would I pick like 100 random ones or something?

Comment: What is `permutate` supposed to return?

Comment: @ScottHunter permutate is the function that brings us all of the variations.

Comment: would this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: @DanielLord I think that would solve my getting random ones, then I just need to log every item from 1 - n,. Thank you.